# Android BroadcastReceiver not running when designated

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am new to android development, and
I have an app that when run from the app icon in the menu / home screens runs just fine. However when I try to make it run on boot completion it crashes (Keeping in mind that if I go back to the Icon it will still work) I am wondering what is wrong here. Keep in mind I am doing testing on my personal phone which is android 2.3 and it is ROOTED. Some how I don't think this should be as hard as it is to do, since 9/10 most android apps work in this way or in a way similar to this. Simply put: What am I doing wrong?

In the mean time here is my code for the Broadcast Receiver:

```
package path.to.file;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class autoBot extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "StartAtBootServiceReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onReceive:");
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("path.to.file.MainActivity");
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

As well as the Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
installlocation="internalOnly"
package="path.to.file"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="autoBot" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            </action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" >
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Add another `intent-filter` to your `MainActivity` in the manifest with the action that you set in the `Intent` used in the `BroadcastReceiver` and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you are adding an action to your intent? If your only aim is to launch your activity at start-up, do this in your BroadcastReceiver:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Also, remove these lines from your manifest under receiver tag, you won't need them there:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" ></category>
```

Comment: It should be noted that, in order to launch an Activity from a BroadcastReceiver, the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` will need to be added to the Intent.

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot and get back to you all with a Yay / nay.

Comment: @babatenor  SUCCESS!!!! Thanks alot! By any chance does anyone know how to make this a notification and or to run it in the background? If need be I can open up a new question regarding this. But it is something I have been messing with all the same..

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark the answer as correct by selecting the green tick next to the answer so that people who have the same problem can benefit in the future. To run it in the background, I recommend you to have a look at Service or IntentService. You can get more help if you start a new question with some code showing that you tried.